# Convert 17 digit with decimal point timestamp in SQL to date

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

Trying to convert 43439.961377314816 into date. Currently I am using this code:

```
SELECT 
    (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT' +
     numtodsinterval(WRITETIMESTAMP, 'SECOND')) at time zone 'CST',
    WRITETIMESTAMP
FROM 
    t.table
```

but I am getting this result:

```
01-JAN-70 06.03.59.961377315 AM CST
```

Date should be:

```
12/05/2018
```

Answer (score 2):

This produces the date that you want:

```
select date '1899-12-30' + 43439.961377314816
from dual;
```

It looks like you are using Excel dates or something similar.

Comment: So what kind of time stamp is this? Unix?

Comment: @user10764658 . . . As I say in the question, I think this is an Excel timestamp.  Nominally, Excel timestamps start with "1" on 1900-01-01.  However, they miscount 1900 as a leap year, so I think that's why it works with 1899-12-30.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your query. First, you used the wrong base time. As pointed out by @GordonLinoff, the base time for an Excel date is actually 1900-01-01, and Excel treats 1900 as a leap year. This is not an error in Excel, per se, but a [conscious design decision](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm) which was made to copy the (buggy) behavior of Lotus 1-2-3, which *did* have this bug. So - in Lotus 1-2-3 it's a bug, but in Excel it's a feature. :-) Secondly, in Excel dates the integer portion represents the number of **days** since the base date, and the fractional portion represent **fraction of a day**. In your `NUMTODSINTERVAL` call, however, you specified the `interval_unit` argument as `'SECOND'`; it should have been `'DAY'`.

Putting these things together we get

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT 43439.961377314816 AS WRITETIMESTAMP FROM DUAL)
SELECT 
    (timestamp '1899-12-30 00:00:00 GMT' + numtodsinterval(WRITETIMESTAMP, 'DAY')) at time zone 'CST',
    WRITETIMESTAMP
FROM 
    cte
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b041fed799f5bd366731a6e720517c99)

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like expected behavior to me. 43439 seconds/60/60 = 12 hours and you're getting about 12 hours from the starting timestamp.

```
SELECT numtodsinterval('43439.961377314816', 'SECOND') as i FROM dual;

I                     
----------------------
+00 12:03:59.961377315
```

Why would you think that would give you a date in 2018?

Comment: The database I am working with records the time a specific files were created and the timestamp I mentioned is recording the file that was created 12/05/18. Also when I export the timestamp into excel the timestamp converts to the right date and the files creation.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a working formula to put in Excel that works for Chromium browsers.
Chrome/Edge: =((Cell/1000000-11644473600)*1000000)/86400000000+DATE(1970,1,1)

Comment: the question is SQL related